# How to find parse keys in Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, parse-platform

I have downloaded an Android App source code from GitHub and converted into an apk file.

Looks like the Developer has used parse backed to store and retrieve data.

Is there a way where those DB authentication details are located so that I can replace with those keys with my keys and use my authentication details.?

Comment: "Is there a way where those DB authentication details are located so that I can replace with those keys with my keys and use my authentication details?" -- since you have the source code, look in the source code for where Parse keys get applied. Feel free to provide a link to the GitHub repo, and perhaps others can help you find the proper location in the source code.

Comment: Yes. My question is where do I look for them?   also here is the github repo link.. https://github.com/triptoes1/WhereIsMyBus

Comment: Well, the Parse documentation provides instructions on how to use their API, including how to use their keys. Beyond that, free to provide a link to the GitHub repo, and perhaps others can help you find the proper location in the source code.

Comment: I have attached the github repo link. I did do a search and tried to do a fiddler to see if I could see any place where I could see an indication. I also looked into the parse jar files to see if there was any info there. Could you please help based on your experience, where should I look for the keys? or maybe insert my keys so that it can talk to my parse db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to Parse, [the keys are passed to `Parse.initialize()`](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new).

A search of the project shows that the developer, for whatever reason, [calls `Parse.initialize()` in several places](https://github.com/triptoes1/WhereIsMyBus/search?q=initialize). You would have to ask the developer why that is the case.

And, in general, committing keys like this to a public place, like a GitHub repo, is not a particularly good idea. Perhaps it's not a huge issue for Parse — I am not a Parse user, so I do not know the rules regarding their keys.